# FTP contents of folder using CRON

Tags: ftp, cron

I don't have much experience with scripts but have been tasked with creating one.  I have a script now running from the cron daily.  The script (.sh) is:

```
/usr/local/bin/ncftpput -f saxlogin.cfg /MTM/PH /mnt/zeus/scripts/xml/pph/2013.04.15/*
```

The script runs fine but what I have to do is go in and change the script daily to reflect today's date (2013.04.15).  Is there a way to set this to change automatically but keep the format of Y.M.D?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using `date +"%Y.%m.%d"` in your path definition?

```
/usr/local/bin/ncftpput -f saxlogin.cfg /MTM/PH /mnt/zeus/scripts/xml/pph/`date +"%Y.%m.%d"`/*
```

Comment: That worked great.  I have another question since that worked so well.  Is there an easy way to automate a process so that if I want this script to run hourly, it can check what files have already been FTPed and skip those and only send new ones?  Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Sure, it can be done! I think it is better to open a new question so that you can post your code and we can answer with full format options - comments are not very comfortable to print code.